# How to read script output from java?

Tags: java, command-line, process

In your Java program you call

```
Process md5Process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command.toString());
```

`command` in this case is a Perl script that prints out a few lines of text.

How can i read these 2 lines inside my Java program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`md5Process.getInputStream()`

and

`md5Process .getErrorStream()`

as described in http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html